# Prefix form of unary operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci, unary-operator, prefix-operator

In GHCi:

> 1. Prelude> (+3) 2
>      5
> 2. Prelude> (*3) 2
>      6
> 3. Prelude> (/3) 2
>      0.6666666666666666
> 4. Prelude> (-3) 2
>      No instance for (Num (t -> t1))
>       arising from the literal `3' at <interactive>:1:2
>
>      Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (t -> t1))
>
>      In the expression: 3
>
>      In the expression: (- 3) 2
>
>      In the definition of`it': it = (- 3) 2

How can I correct the last one to make it return -1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haskell's grammar doesn't allow you to use `-` like that. Use the `subtract` function instead:

```
(subtract 3) 2
```

Answer (score 9):

As a footnote to [grddev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406320/prefix-form-of-unary-operator-in-haskell/3406369#3406369), here's the relevant paragraph from the [Haskell 98 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html):

> The special form `-e` denotes prefix
>   negation, the only prefix operator in
>   Haskell, and is syntax for `negate
>   (e)`. The binary `-` operator does not
>   necessarily refer to the definition of
>   `-` in the Prelude; it may be rebound by the module system. However, unary `-`
>   will always refer to the `negate`
>   function defined in the Prelude. There
>   is no link between the local meaning
>   of the `-` operator and unary negation.

This is something that frustrated me when I first came across it: I couldn't understand why the operators behaved so differently in this context when `:info (+)` and `:info (-)` looked basically identical.

You could use `subtract`, as grddev suggests, or you could just define a new infix operator:

```
Prelude> let (#) = (-)
Prelude> (# 3) 2
-1
```

`subtract` has the advantage of being familiar to other people who might read your code.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
(-) 3 2
```

but that will give you 1. To have -1, you need to bind the 3 to the second argument of -, which you can do using

```
flip (-) 3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're intent on keeping your original shape, you can always add the negative:

```
(+ -3)
```

It ain't pretty, but it fits your pattern a little bit more.

Comment: Yep, he should have said `(+ (-3))`.  To make a negative number you need the `-` and number in parenthesis.

Comment: Another (maybe a bit ugly) way would be `(-3+) 2`.