# Haskell handling negative parameters

Tags: haskell

Trying to sum two values, with only one of them negative, such as `-1` and `2`:

```
soma :: Float -> Float -> Float
soma x1 x2 = x1 + x2
```

The result in an error; WHY?

```
<interactive>:10:6:
No instance for (Num (Float -> Float -> Float))
  arising from a use of `-'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Num (Float -> Float -> Float))
In the expression: soma - 1 2
In an equation for `it': it = soma - 1 2
```

Comment: it should be -1 (no space in between).

Comment: Really try it; there's no space

Comment: ok, then it should be (-1), sry

Comment: Yes, it works but it's a poor solution; why is it an error? Did you have ever seen this?

Comment: It is the only (and good) solution. Look at how expressions are evaluated in haskell (hint: soma gets applied on the unary minus operator and it complains it is not a float).

Answer (score 15):

You should use (-1) instead of - 1.  The parser interprets what you typed as (-) soma (1 2).  In other words, it tried to subtract (1 2) from soma.  Which doesn't work because subtract doesn't accept a Float -> Float -> Float.

What you would like (and expected to happen) was for haskell to evaluate the - as a unary operator on 1, with higher precedence than the function application.  This would be contrary to the way haskell normally works.  There already is special consideration for (-1) being interpreted as (negate 1).  [This can cause some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406692/854861), by virtue of being a special case - in the example trying to curry the - doesn't work because it isn't really -, but negate.

Presumably an even broader special case carved out for - would lead to even more behavior unexpected by experienced haskell programmers and so the language designers decided it wasn't worth it.

Comment: But, as minus is a unary operator, when typed without a space after, it SHOULD be interpreted as a unary operator and so, not be separated from the number following it.

Comment: But it's perfectly valid to pass a unary operator as a parameter to another function.  If by SHOULD you are disagreeing with the language's design philosophy, that is your right, though I would advise reserving judgement until you have a sense of how it all hangs together.

Comment: My point is: I agree minus is a parameter IF is separated by a space from the number following. If I write -1 2, why is it not interpreted just as 2 parameters; it's different from - 1 2

Comment: I don't think people think needing to use parenthesis to make a negative number is ideal, but given the rest of the language syntax it's a problem that is very hard to fix without breaking other features that are desirable.

Comment: "But, as minus is a unary operator," - no, it isn't. It's binary subtraction, and the language has a special rule that says that the section `(-x)` is not interpreted as `(\y -> y - x)` like with any other operator, but as `(negate x)`

Comment: @Ingo Thank you.  I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @psr Actually the parser interprets his expression `soma - 1 2` as `(-) soma (1 2)`. That explains the complaints about a function not being an instance of Num.

Comment: @Ingo - Er, maybe you should answer and I should just delete this?

Comment: @psr :) Due to my exposure to Haskell, I was too lazy to write an answer. But I always stand ready to clear up confusions whre they arise.

Comment: @user109964: Indeed it would be perfectly reasonably to parse `-[0-9]*\..[0-9]` as one token, and use that as a single (negative) literal. But the language standard says otherwise. Not everything is done ideally in Haskell! The related quirk of `(-x)` not being an operator section is even more annoying IMO. Wonder if we could have a `{-# LANGUAGE UnaryMinusIsLiteralPrefix #-}` extension... this basic idea [was already brought up here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NegativeSyntax).