# How to use error in a Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am using GHCI 7.10.3 and I'm getting error in a simple fatorial code.

I would like to do something like this:

```
fatorial n
    | n == 0  = 1
    | n > 0 = n * fatorial(n-1)
    | otherwise = error "My error"
```

But when `fatorial -4` was called, the output was:

> :21:1:
>       Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a)
>       (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
>       When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
>         it :: forall a. (Num a, Num (a -> a), Ord a) => a -> a

My code works fine without the last line. So how can I use error message in haskell?

Comment: That is because Haskell has interpreted it as `factorial - 4` (so a subtraction), you should use `factorial (-4)`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20391391/67579

Comment: I don't really believe "My code works fine without the last line". What makes you think that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the error is a type error, so that means that Haskell thinks that what you wrote makes no sense (from a type system point of view).

It interprets the `-` as the "*binary minus operator*", like:

```
--         v operator
factorial  -  4
-- ^  operand ^
```

So Haskell thinks you want to subtract `4` from `factorial`, but it does not see how `factorial` is a `Num`ber, hence the error. Strictly speaking, one *can* make functions `Num`bers, as long as one implements the [**`Num` typeclass**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) (as well as the [**`Eq`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) and [**`Show`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show) typeclasses) we are fine.

If you want to use negative number literals in such function call, you need to use brackets, like:

```
factorial (-4)
```

This then produces:

```
Prelude> fatorial (-4)
*** Exception: My error
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:5:19 in interactive:Ghci1
```

So now it raises your `error "My error"` (see the first output line).

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your help. Here is fatorial (pt language...). ;)

Comment: @eightShirt: aah, I removed the note :)